# How could liquid nitrogen weapons exist in a medieval society?

Tags: weapons, civilization, low-fantasy

It’s been awhile since I’ve been on here, and in all that time, I’ve developed my fictional world by a lot.
But I’m still confused by something. 
You see, the society of my world is one modeled on Europe during the Middle Ages, yet they possess firearms. Unlike normal guns, these don’t use gunpowder or bullets, rather, they use liquid nitrogen.
My question is, could there be a way for a primitive society to develop weapons like this?

Comment: Is it stated in your fiction where they get liquid nitrogen from?  Or is that the question: how to produce liquid nitrogen with medieval tech?

Comment: Almost anything "could" be possible. However, it beggars belief, so you better be a very good storyteller to handwave how this barbaric kingdom can liquefy air but doesn't understand how to prevent the bubonic plague nor apply any of the ancilliary energy and industrial technologies...which it somehow obtained and uses without any schools...to improve the impoverished quality of life.

Comment: Worth noting also that while liquefying air is by far the largest obstacle, storing the stuff in a battlefield-usable container would require metallurgy that they _also_ wouldn't have available, and projecting it under pressure would require materials science that they wouldn't have available. So whole disciplines of study would need to be present, which would make _conventional_ firearms far more reasonable.

Comment: No it's not possible. However if you still want to use this idea then it might be possible to suspend disbelief in some people who were not familiar with the technology.

Comment: Not without resorting to magic of some sort, but I had a D&D campaign with guns powered by fire trap spells (that 'opened' into the barrel), so why not?

Comment: Even our modern technological society can't produce any practical firearms which use liquid nitrogen as propellant, so...

Comment: Do you have a sense of what the liquid nitrogen is supposed to do inside the guns, or is that the question?  Most of the answers so far seem to be focused on the challenge of getting liquid nitrogen, but finding a way to use it in anything resembling a firearm is hard too.

Comment: "these don’t use gunpowder or bullets, rather, they use [an element that rapidly expands upon release]" : [Girandoni air rifle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girardoni_air_rifle) "made from hammered sheet iron held together with rivets and sealed by brazing, proved very difficult to manufacture using the techniques of the period and were always in short supply." - both braising and rivets are c. 3000 BC. The degree to which you handwave "very difficult to manufacture" is your prerogative.

Comment: Medieval society was hardly primitive.

Comment: How common are the weapons?  Everyone has one over the fireplace?  Basic weapon for any military or guard force, but not generally available to the populace?  Only available to the elite?  If relatively rare, then a rare magic system could explain how weapons and/or ammunition is created.

Comment: You can't use liquid nitrogen as a propellant because it doesn't melt fast enough. Even compressed air is only good for bb guns which would be useless on a battle field.

Comment: Related question: [How to make a 'freeze' weapon work?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25541/how-to-make-a-freeze-weapon-work)

Comment: Liquid nitrogen is a horrible weapon. A teacher used to throw half a flask of the stuff at the class at the end of his demo, and it would evaporate before it got to the front row. This isn't at all like the movies.

Comment: If you're willing to scale back to just dry ice (solid CO2), it's slightly easier to produce (it was first discovered in the 1830's, vs. the 1880s for liquid nitrogen).  It might be feasible for a modern time traveler to produce it in medieval times.  Mind you, it's even less effective as a weapon, except perhaps for assassination by asphyxiation via displacing oxygen in a poorly ventilated room.

Answer (score 19):

> could there be a way for a primitive society to develop weapons like this?

No.

- [liquefying air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_air) is well beyond medieval tech level.

  > The most common process for the preparation of liquid air is the two-column Hampson–Linde cycle using the Joule–Thomson effect. Air is fed at high pressure (>60 psig, or 520 kPa) into the lower column, in which it is separated into pure nitrogen and oxygen-rich liquid. The rich liquid and some of the nitrogen are fed as reflux into the upper column, which operates at low pressure (<10 psig, or 170 kPa), where the final separation into pure nitrogen and oxygen occurs. A raw argon product can be removed from the middle of the upper column for further purification.
  >
  > Air can also be liquefied by Claude's process, which combines cooling by Joule–Thomson effect, isentropic expansion and regenerative cooling.
- handling liquid nitrogen is also well beyond medieval technology, and rather unpractical even in modern times. Surely not something you want on a battlefield.

Comment: Pretty sure it _would_ be possible to liquefy air with much more primitive means than what the modern industrial processes use, if you don't mind bad energy efficiency. ...not with medieval means though, that's true.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from being cool (pun intended) what would be the use of a liquid nitrogen weapon? It's really not that dangerous!

Liquid nitrogen is cold; but it has a pretty low heat capacity so unless you pour a bucket directly on someone it's not going to do a lot, and the gas itself is entirely harmless. A common disposal method is just to pour it on the ground outside, and you don't even have to take too much care while doing so. You'd do far more damage with conventional chemicals like hot oil or acids.

The most dangerous thing you can do with liquid nitrogen is have it in an enclosed space and let it displace all the oxygen; an intriguing and subtle way to assassinate a pesky king, but not really a weapon in the conventional sense.

Comment: You missed the obvious one - rapid expansion of liquid to gas... just like firearms do, but solid to gas in that case. You can certainly create "bombs" with it in an enclosed tube. I imagine you could use it to propel a bullet too.

Answer (score 6):

> could there be a way for a primitive society to develop weapons like this?

**Yes...**

...in a slightly kinky, low fantasy world, one can imagine how such "firearms" work. For example:

your armoury could make use of *cryogrobbins*, a kind of wee imp that destills nitrogen from the air as a byproduct of its own respiration. This is for the cryogrobbin a waste product that it periodically pisses through relatively normal methods.

Your gunsmiths will take advantage of this faculty by fixing one cryogrobbin to a kind of cartridge in such a way that the poor wee fellow is bunged up. This builds up pressure in the bladder over time. When it comes time to load the gunne, the musqueteer will simply grab a pre-bunged crygrobbin cartridge from his pouch and shove the poor fellow into the breach of the gunne and pack the ball in from the muzzle. When it comes time to fire the gunne, the musqueteer pulls the trigger which releases the bung and applies pressure to the cryogrobbin's abdomen, forcing a rapid & explosive discharge of liquid nitrogen.

The rapid discharge and expansion propels the projectile in the expected manner.

Magic. Pure magic.

Comment: Yes pure magic. Why not do away with the goblin thing and just magic the liquid nitrogen into existence when you need it. That would also solve the storage problem.

Comment: Indeed! Magic applied to technology. This is a "low fantasy" setting after all. If you ignore the inherent magic, you can't really offer a viable solution.

Comment: Or there could have been some journey long ago to a cold region of the Earth where the explorers stumbled across...etc.  Perhaps it's not exactly "liquid nitrogen" but it certainly does what you need it to do.

Comment: This is probably the funniest answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

It would not be possible to create liquid nitrogen using medieval technology.

However for the purposes of a story, it might be possible to suspend disbelief in some people (who were not familiar with any cryogenic technology), although even then it would still be very difficult.

How about a large ship with the hull sealed with lead sheeting and capsized in deep water by adding some huge rocks to the mast. Then take a tube to the surface and let the highly compressed air caught in the hull out. If enough air rushes out and expands rapidly at the surface and the process continues for long enough the temperature should drop.

You’re not really going to get liquid nitrogen by this method, but you might be able to fool some people this way.

Alternatively since your not using the science based tab just use magic.

Comment: OP has already placed the [low fantasy] tag: "worlds where magic exists, but is rare".

Answer (score 0):

It won't work for mediaeval humans in a terrestrial setting. There are only two ways to change the phase of the gas, cooling and compression. The tech of the day can't provide adequate seals or refrigeration.

Aliens on a gas giant is another story. They could do with with a winch, a long rope and an insulated bottle.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, liquid nitrogen isn't really possible or practical.

One liquid that is available that *could* be more dangerous than liquid nitrogen is alcohol, which can be cooled down to temperatures well below the coldest places on earth. It also has a much higher boiling point, and tends to stick to things it touches, including skin.

If you had a means of cooling the liquid down, say, dragging it up a cold mountain, cooling it, and then bringing it back down quickly (maybe via a slide or something), you could possibly load it into device that sprays it, causing frostbite.

Distilling would be cumbersome, though, and this could be a resource-intensive process.

Additionally, propelling the liquid would be difficult, especially in a manner that would allow it to remain insulated for months at a time, which one might need on a military campaign. It would be extremely heavy to carry around in a large container that would be able to insulate it.

Also, it would be nearly impossible to use over a long range. Air resistance and turbulence would increase the temperature and slow down the launched liquid, limiting both its range and effectiveness.

For defensive purposes, such as pouring a large container of it over a wall, it might be more practical, but hot tar/oil also does the trick, but requires less preparation/maintenance.

Perhaps you could find some sort of highly endothermic reaction involving two chemicals commonly available (perhaps produced by some creature, as others have suggested), and they violently react in in a way that draws in heat from their surroundings (e.g., air, skin, water, themselves.). A projectile could simply include both chemicals separated in a pouch that tears upon hitting a target. It could also have secondary poisonous effects that would eventually kill/maim the target.